# Why do std::flat_set and std::flat_map have overloaded constructors for std::initializer_list while other container adapters don't?

Tags: c++, stl, initializer-list, c++23, stdstack

I noticed that C++23 added new overloads for the `std::stack` and `std::queue` container adapters' constructors, which allow to construct the underlying container with the contents of the range `[first, last)`. cppreference also shows how these overloads can be used with `std::initializer_list`, and provides the following examples:

```cpp
const auto il = {2, 7, 1, 8, 2};
std::stack<int> c4 { il.begin(), il.end() }; // overloads (6), C++23

const auto il = {2, 7, 1, 8, 2};
std::queue<int> c4 { il.begin(), il.end() }; // overload (6), C++23
```

This means that introducing other overloaded constructors in order to construct the underlying container with the contents of an `std::initialization_list` is not necessary.
However, C++23 had added also other container adapters, such as `std::flat_set`, and cppreference shows an example of implementation of the `std::flat_set` container adapter, where the following overloaded constructors are provided:

```cpp
flat_set(initializer_list<key_type> il, const key_compare& comp = key_compare())
 : flat_set(il.begin(), il.end(), comp) { }

template<class Allocator>
flat_set(initializer_list<key_type> il, const key_compare& comp, const Allocator& a);

template<class Allocator>
flat_set(initializer_list<key_type> il, const Allocator& a);
```

Why do `std::flat_set` and `std::flat_map` have overloaded constructors for `std::initializer_list` while other container adapters don't?

Comment: There's no specific rationale in the [proposal](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p0429r9.pdf) why it was included. And as usual, it could burn down to the no-brainer *nobody cared to write a proposal to add those constructors to the conventional container adaptors*.

Comment: Could also be an optimization given that the flat_set and flat_map instances are going to use contiguous memory, much like an initializer_list.

Comment: I think the issue with `queue` and `stack` is that they are not natural containers - they are container adapters - they adapt another container and provide different reduced interface. `stack` uses `vector` by default while `queue` uses `dequeue` by default.

Comment: Say you can directly initialize a stack from initializer list by creating a `std::vector` as an intermidiate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll copy my std-proposals answer here, since it covers a bit more than LoS's own answer above.

First, a quotation from [P2447R3](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2447r3.html):

> Yes, *any* change to overload sets (particularly the addition of new non-explicit constructors) can break code. But that's not necessarily a proposal-killer. For example, there was nothing wrong with C++23’s adopting [[P1425] "Iterator-pair constructors for stack and queue"](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p1425r4.pdf) with no change to [Annex C](https://eel.is/c++draft/diff.cpp20), despite its breaking code like this:
>
> ```
> void zero(queue<int>);
> void zero(pair<int*,int*>);
> int a[10];
> void test() { zero({a, a+10}); }
> ```
>
> Before: Calls `zero(pair<int, int>)`.
> After P1425: Ambiguous.
> To fix: Eliminate the ambiguous overloading, or cast the argument to `pair`.
>
> We can simply agree that such examples are sufficiently unlikely in practice, and sufficiently easy to fix, that the benefits of the changed overload set outweigh the costs of running into these examples.

Then I wrote:

> I think `priority_queue` *should* get an `initializer_list` ctor, because we
> all know what `priority_queue<int> pq = {1,2,3}` ought to do.
> I think `queue` *probably* should get an `initializer_list` ctor, because I
> assume we all know what `queue<int> q = {1,2,3}` ought to do: items pop from
> the front of the queue, so "1" would be at the front, right?
> I'm more skeptical of `stack`. I don't think anyone would guess better than
> 50/50 what `stack<int> st = {1,2,3}` ought to do, as written. Items pop from
> the "top" of a stack, yes, but is that the left end or the right end?
> (Experts know it must be the right end because that's the only efficient
> end when the container is a vector; but I don't think that's terribly
> obvious.) However, on the other hand, it's true that the iterator-pair
> ctor Does The Right Thing: if you push 1, then 2, then 3, you end up with
> an underlying vector containing `{1,2,3}`. So why not just let the programmer
> write `{1,2,3}` in the first place? So I'm skeptical, but not completely anti.
>
> Anyway, in all of those cases, adding new ctors will change overload sets —
> and change them drastically, because `initializer_list` ctors are even
> greedier than other non-explicit ctors. (This is why implicit conversions
> are the devil, and the STL's prevailing style of "make everything implicit
> unless there's a positive reason to make it explicit" [is the Wrong Default](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2023/04/08/most-ctors-should-be-explicit/)
> as usual. Python got it right.) So that's probably why LEWG has been leery
> of doing so.
>
> OTOH, `flat_set` and `flat_map` are completely novel class types; nobody
> has any existing code that would be broken by fiddling with their overload
> sets.
> And `flat_set` is supposed to be a drop-in replacement for `set`! So
> obviously it would be a non-starter if you could write
>
> ```
> std::set<int> s = {1,2,3};
> ```
>
> but not
>
> ```
> std::flat_set<int> s = {1,2,3};
> ```
>
> That just *has* to work, period.

Answer (score 2):

I answer my question in order to provide a complete answer for those who will be interested in this topic.

After proposing the introduction of the overloaded constructors for `std::initializer_list` in [Std-proposals](https://lists.isocpp.org/std-proposals/2023/03/5989.php), it has been discovered that it would be very difficult to add an overloaded constructor for `std::initializer_list` to the `std::stack` and `std::queue` container adapters without a serious risk to break existing code.
An example could be the following:

```cpp
Obj* p, q;

[...]

std::stack s{p, q};
```

This could lead to a problem if the overloaded constructor for `std::initializer_list` were introduced as it could produce a `std::deque<Obj*>` underlying container constructed with the two pointers instead of a `std::deque<Obj>` constructed with the elements in the range of elements `[p, q)`.
This issue does not arise for the `std::flat_set` and `std::flat_map` container adapters as the overloaded constructors have already been provided from the beginning, and therefore there is not risk to have problems of compatibility.